# Validating Date Range Produced By jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, validation, uidatepicker

I am using the [date picker provided by jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker) to select a date range that ends up in a  single text input with something like 11/11/2008 - 12/05/2008. What would you recommend as far a validation (jQuery/JavaScript) on the client side as well as code for validation on the server side (ASP.NET/C#) to make sure the user enters valid dates?

Note I [asked a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311576/parsing-a-date-range-in-c-aspnet) the other day about how to parse out the two dates using C# if your interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).  Should be fairly simple to split these into two separate dates, parse each, and compare as necessary to verify the range is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare Dates with javascript fairly easily, just convert inputs to Date objects, and then any comparator would work. I use Date.js, as it has an excellent parser.  On the backend, I would assume that you can do the same thing, the key is to convert all your objects to the same type, and one that can be compared to another.